# Return binary stream as response to request playframework

Tags: scala, playframework

i have problem with returning binary stream from play framework. According to documentation, the framework should automatically return binary output if it finds that the controller method returns either Stream or File. Well my method returns a Stream[Byte] but the framework returns "Stream(100, ?)" rather then the binary stream.

What do i do wrong?
Thanks for the answers, 
Tomas Herman

---

**edit**

ok in case anyone needs this in the future, it looks like i somehow hacked it together. I just build a string from the Stream and return that. It seems to be working correctly but i'm sure there is some better solution.

example:

```
val builder = new StringBuilder()
builder.clear
stream foreach { x=> builder.append(x.toChar)}
val res = builder.toString
```

where res is what your controller method is supposed to return

Answer (score 0):

You might have gotten what you need. `Stream(100, ?)` is a `Stream` whose first value is `100`, and the remaining values have not yet been evaluated. To see it fully, try printing `stream mkString ("Stream(", ", ", ")")`.

Comment: Yes but I actually need Play framework to send the content of the stream into the web browser (or in my case a BitTorrent client). At the moment, i think, it only sends the toString value of the object

Comment: @Arg If that's the case, either don't use a `Stream`, or do some no-op that will force it to evaluate completely (eg, `val noop = stream.mkString`).

Comment: yeah solved it using the function i added to the OP. I just somehow expected that playframework would accept a Stream as output from controller method. Seems somewhat natural to me. Anyway thanks for the replays!